# Can't figure out the mistake here,

Tags: python

I'm new to this and trying to complete a workshop. Keeps giving the "2nd department" as the answer and is frustrating me.    It should give the answer as "1st Department" for CP and/or Down.

```
d1 = ["CP", "Down", "SMA", "Bone Fracture", "Hemiplegia"]
patient =input("What's your complaint? = ")
data = True

for patient in d1:
    if patient == "SMA" or "Bone Fracture" or "Hemiplegia":
        data = False
        break

if data:
    print("1st Department")
else:
    print("2nd Department")
```

Comment: This is so common, python could be smarter and throw a warning when a user implicitly tests truthiness of a string literal

Comment: ^job of a linter.

Comment: Nothing wrong in typing, 0 red underlined words. Just keeps giving the same answer

Comment: ```if any(patient==x for x in d1)```

Comment: I removed the "for" loop and edit the code as " if patient in ("SMA", "Bone Fracture", "Hemiplegia"):
        data = False"  now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` condition to:

`if patient in ["SMA", "Bone Fracture", "Hemiplegia"]:`

You can also probably simplify the code to:

```
d1 = ["CP", "Down", "SMA", "Bone Fracture", "Hemiplegia"]
patient =input("What's your complaint? = ")
data = patient in d1

if data:
    print("1st Department")
else:
    print("2nd Department")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but sadly did not work

Comment: See edit for revised code.